# Кросс-авторизацию по ssh-ключам

Tags: авторизация, ssh, debian

Ребят, подскажите, как обеспечить кросс-авторизацию по ssh-ключам на всех четырех машинах?
Закрытую часть ssh ключа хранить на машинах нельзя. Т.е. чтобы можно было пройти по цепочке 1я машина -> 2я машина -> 3я машина -> 4я машина без ввода паролей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На первой машине придется хранить секретную часть ключа и добавлять ее в `ssh-agent`:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Если используете pytty для захода, то используйте pagent, и так-же в SSH сессии putty разрешите форвард агента.

Добавить в `~/.ssh/config` во всех машинах:

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
```

или запускать:

```
$ ssh -A user@host
```

Основная мысль - ключ хранится в агенте на одной машине, а все остальные ходят к этому агенту за ключами.

Answer (score 1):

Взять паблик ключ от первой машины и добавить его в ~/.ssh/authorized_keys во второй машине. Действие повторить для 2й и 3й машины ...